# Spring security openID attribute access

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, openid, google-openid

My questions is similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140519/spring-security-with-openid-for-google-not-working-in-production-environment).

But I am using Spring security 3.1.4 in which following call is deprecated.

```
(OpenIDAuthenticationToken)exception.getAuthentication()
```

What is the alternative mechanism to get `OpenIDAuthenticationToken` in `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` implementation?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirement is to register users who are not already in your system, you can do that in the same way that the [sample application does](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/openid-xml/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/openid/CustomUserDetailsService.java#L47).

If you need more interaction with the user at that point, then the only alternative to the deprecated method that springs to mind would be to use your own custom exception.

Comment: Custom exception also doesn't help here (based on my research). I had to create custom user object and access it from SecurityContextHolder, which is working as expected. Do you see any issues with this approach?

Comment: This should work. Once the OpenID authentication is complete, you could give them a role such as 'ROLE_REGISTERING' which only gives them access to the registration pages until the process is complete, at which point you can upgrade the account (and authentication object) to give full site access. A custom exception should be just the same as the code you've posted above, but without the deprecated method, so I don't see why it should be a problem.

Comment: Rather than doing that in UserDetailsService just write your own AuthenticationProvider which does what you say - return that authentication with authenticated = true but some special privileges.